# sequencing by seconds w/ some simple arithmetic 

Tags: r, posixct

```
x <-80

 test <- seq(from=as.POSIXct('x - 1',format='%M'),to=as.POSIXct('x +
 1',format='%M'),by='sec')
 # this doesn't actually work
```

what I'm trying to do is create a sequence here in increments of seconds, but I would like to incorporate some simple arithmetic in my 'to' and 'from' arguments.

the above code obviously doesn't work, could I get some help?

I need something that can work for numerical values greater and less than 60.

Comment: i didn't realize that numbers over 60 would be a problem if the format was minutes

Comment: "So to speak"??? What is meant by that? It's going to be modestly  difficult to create increments of for differences of 2 minutes when your values only differ by 2 seconds , i.e. the natural unit for POSIX objects. You also do NOT want them to be passed as character values.

Comment: the objects don't differ by 2 seconds, but 2 minutes

Comment: What do you want the output to be?

Comment: an array, in seconds of whatever window i give it, in this case x -1 and x + 1

Comment: So, you want fractional seconds?

Comment: what do you mean fractional seconds? I just want seconds, like 1.01 meaning one minute one second, I can format later. If you can help me out w/ getting colon separated values that is fine, your answer is good, except for values above 60 obviously

Comment: Your edits did not fix the fundamental problem, namely that you were offering an incomprehensible character argument to as.POSIXct() so it was NOT dispatching to seq.POSIXt. And you have only clarified in the comments but not in the question text that you thought (mistakenly) that this was going to give you a span of 2 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
test <- seq(from=strptime(x - 1, format='%M'),
            to=strptime(x + 1, format='%M'),
            by='sec')
```

You can then `format` however you please.

Do take a look at `?strptime` because it is a very useful help page that you will likely reference many times as you work with dates/times in R.

---

You can put the good advice of @plannapus to work like this

```
tmp <- seq(strptime(paste((x-1)%/%60, (x-1)%%60, sep=":"), format="%H:%M"), 
           strptime(paste((x+1)%/%60, (x+1)%%60, sep=":"), format="%H:%M"), 
           by='sec')
as.numeric(format(tmp, "%M.%S"))
```

But, you really ought to rethink your problem and/or provide more info about what you're trying to do because my guess is that there is a better way to do whatever you're doing.

Comment: hmm..what about for values that are given in minutes like 173 for example, I can't seem to get that to work

Comment: so by that I mean values in which minutes are greater than 60, should/can I convert that first somehow

Comment: Both those comments fail to parse as natural English.

Comment: @Doug what about something along the line of `strptime(paste((x-1)%/%60, (x-1)%%60, sep=":"), format="%H:%M")`?

Comment: @plannapus, i'm not sure i follow the paste and both subtractions

Comment: @DOug `%/%` is the integer division, `%%` is the modulo operation, so if `x <- 173`, `x%/%60` is 2 and `x%%60` is 53, and indeed 173m is 2h53m. `paste(x%/%60, x%%60, sep=":")` gives you `"2:53"`.